# SSRS : When I click an "Action" tab and run HTML, I want thet this Specific row to be Marked

Tags: reporting-services, action

In my work in SSRS I have a column(a textBox with an image) that I have implemented an "Action" tab.
The Action tab opens an HTML that updates my table in the DB [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKtLh.png)

What I want to do is, once I click on the image the entire row will be highlighted as seen in pic.2 (and the Action Tab continues working)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7ulU.png)

Thank you very much and sorry if my English is not good,
Ben

Comment: This cannot be done. You can pass line values as parameters and display them in your data entry form, so the user will know which line he edits

Comment: Hypothetically you could capture the line he is on as a parm, then have the action rerun the same report with it being highlighted if the current row was the passed in row. I don't know about combining this with an HTML action, it seems like you could do one but not both.   Basically, SSRS shows you a rendered report, not really what you would call a fulling interactive one.